# Spring Boot 2.0 request mapping issue with OpenJDK 11.0.2

Tags: java, spring-boot

Issue that I'm facing is that I'm unable to get any response on hitting the URL -> **http://localhost:9293/hello**

There are no issues, no errors or any logs while I attempt to test this minimalist feature but no luck with this. Any suggestions or leads are most welcome!

Please do let me know if you need any further information on the question!.

Spring Version: **2.1.5.RELEASE**

OpenJDK Version: **11.0.2**

**application.properties**

```
server.port=9293
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

**HelloWorldController.java**
    package com.sample.springboot.jwt.controller;

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping({ "/hello" })
    public String firstPage() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

My main class, **SpringBootJwtApplication**
    package com.sample.springboot.jwt.demo;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootJwtApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootJwtApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("From the main() method...");
    }
}
```

And here is my **pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sample.springboot.rest.jwt.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring-Boot-JWT</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring-Boot-JWT</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot using HTTP GET, POST. Securing the application with Spring Boot Security plus JWT</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <!-- version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

**EDIT-1:** Adding my Project structure ->
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to change `spring.mvc.servlet.path` to `server.servlet.context-path`.

check this link for the [change](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12971)

**Updated**

As per your project structure the controller not get scanned by Application Class. So You can move Application to `com.sample.springboot` package .

Comment: I work with java 12 . it is working for me . @N00bPr0grammer

Comment: Whichever Spring Boot tutorial that I look at, it is the similar code but doesn't work for me... Do you see any reason why these issues can occur?

Comment: To be honest no idea . But I just copy paste whatever you shared and try to run it's working only thing i have changed is property .

Comment: I have one more doubt where do you keep your `HelloWorldController` ?

Comment: Can you move your application class to `com.sample.springboot` and check . ?

Comment: Updated the question with the Project structure @soorapadman!

Comment: Moved the class up two levels, above Controller class - Voila! It worked @soorapadman... Ty vm! You may update your answer with these details too! Might help others!

Answer (score 0):

Please Modify your application.properties.

```
server.port=9293
server.servlet.context-path=/
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

Provided wrong context property key

> spring.mvc.servlet.path

Second, you must have to extend the

> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer

```
public class SpringBootJwtApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer
```

Comment: This change didn't help much though @Kumar Panchal!

Comment: Still, the same issue occurring?

Comment: public class SpringBootJwtApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer

please extend spring boot servlet intializer

Comment: No @Kumar Panchal, no difference even now!

Comment: Please add in your pom.xml file below dependency.

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>